# How to make a JButton in a JTable cell click-able?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with a custom cell renderer. The cell is a JPanel that contains a JTextField and a JButton. The JTextField contains an integer, and when the user clicks on the JButton the integer should be increased.

The problem is that the JButton can't be clicked when I have it in a JTable cell. How can I make it click-able?

[image]

Here is my test code:

```
public class ActiveTable extends JFrame {

    public ActiveTable() {
        RecordModel model = new RecordModel();
        model.addRecord(new Record());
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        EditorAndRenderer editorAndRenderer = new EditorAndRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, editorAndRenderer);
        table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, editorAndRenderer);
        table.setRowHeight(38);

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Active Table");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ActiveTable();
            }
        });
    }

    class RecordModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return records.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return records.get(rowIndex);
        }

        public void addRecord(Record r) {
            records.add(r);
            fireTableRowsInserted(records.size()-1, records.size()-1);
        }

    }

    class Record {
        private int count = 1;
        public int getCount() { return count; }
        public void increase() { count = count + 1; }
    }

    class CellPanel extends JPanel {
        private Record record;
        private final JTextField field = new JTextField(8);
        private final Action increaseAction = new AbstractAction("+") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                record.increase();
                field.setText(record.getCount()+"");
                JTable table = (JTable) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTable.class, (Component) e.getSource());
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
            }
        };
        private final JButton button = new JButton(increaseAction);

        public CellPanel() {
            add(field);
            add(button);
        }

        public void setRecord(Record r) {
            record = r;
            field.setText(record.getCount()+"");
        }

        public Record getRecord() {
            return record;
        }
    }

    class EditorAndRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        private final CellPanel renderer = new CellPanel();
        private final CellPanel editor = new CellPanel();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            renderer.setRecord((Record) value);
            return renderer;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            editor.setRecord((Record) value);
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getRecord();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject ev) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject ev) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need an _cellEditor_ instead of an _cellRenderer_ - see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Comment: can you still needed JPanel (nested  Whatever JComponents) inside JTable's cell ??,

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes, I need the cell to be a multi-line JPanel with multiple buttons.

Comment: wait sec. I posted this code here maybe twice or more (somewhere to the JList rellated q&a), if I can't find that, then I'll start search for that in local PC ....

Comment: let's this idea help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355544/how-to-implement-dynamic-gui-in-swing/6355910#6355910

Comment: that same as you put JPanel wiht own logic to the JFrame, JTable is only the Container nothing else :-), that nothing with TableCellEditor or TableCelRenderer, please take example @trashgod, his majesty changing value from one TableCell to the another, but this not your issue, isn't

Comment: @mKorbel: The code you linked to solved finally my problem. You should post it or a link to is as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @mKorbel: The big difference between my code in the question and your code was that you use `DefaultTableModel` and I use `AbstractTableModel`. When using `AbstractTableModel` I have to implement `isCellEditable()` otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: ??? you can override isCellEditable() same for DefalutXxxXxx as an AbstractXxxXxx ???, thanks for offer, no accepted, please answer your question by yourself, btw my +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I based my last example on the code provided by mKrobels answer to [How to implement dynamic GUI in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6355910/213269)

The main difference between his and my example in the question is that he use `DefaultTableModel` and I use `AbstractTableModel`. His example does work, but not mine.

The solution I found was that I had to implement `isCellEditable()` in the TableModel, so with this method added, my example works:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way to use [`ButtonColumn`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

```
public class TableTest extends JFrame {

    public TableTest() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTable table = new JTable(new TestModel());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(3);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(3);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        Action increase = new AbstractAction("+") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                int row = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
                TestModel model = (TestModel) table.getModel();
                model.increment(row, 0);
            }
        };
        ButtonColumn inc = new ButtonColumn(table, increase, 1);
        Action decrease = new AbstractAction("-") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                int row = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
                TestModel model = (TestModel) table.getModel();
                model.decrement(row, 0);
            }
        };
        ButtonColumn dec = new ButtonColumn(table, decrease, 2);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TestModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    List<TestRecord> records = new LinkedList<TestRecord>();

    private static class TestRecord {

        private int val = 0;
    }

    public void increment(int row, int col) {
        records.get(row).val++;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
    }

    public void decrement(int row, int col) {
        records.get(row).val--;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
    }

    public TestModel() {
        records.add(new TestRecord());
        records.add(new TestRecord());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return Integer.class;
        } else {
            return ButtonColumn.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return records.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return records.get(row).val;
        } else if (col == 1) {
            return "+";
        } else {
            return "-";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The renderer is just a display for painting the cells. You need an editor component that allows you to make changes.

Take a look at:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html

Comment: I don't understand how I can use a `TableCellEditor` since my cell contains multiple components and only one of them, the `JButton` should be clickable. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonas, the getTableCellRendererComponent() can return a panel that has buttons, text, etc on it.