# JButton in JList Handling

Tags: java, jbutton, jlist

I want to have a `JButton` (for removing the item) in a `JList`.
Button when I add the `JButton` to my `JList`, the handler doesn't work...
I know it's only rendered,.. but how I can I make it - that I recognize the `actionPerformed`?
Maybe, someone have a code-snippet?

I add a vector-list of `JPanels`, and inside of these `JPanels` there are my `JButton` and `JLabel`.

Comment: Could you provide some code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) would be better JComponents as [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), because there you can implements TableCellEditor, maybe example with similair output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355544/how-to-implement-dynamic-gui-in-swing/6355910#6355910)

Comment: +1 for the table suggestion. Check out the [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for code to display the button and do the delete.