# Dynamic JPanel addition

Tags: swing, jpanel, java

I am trying to create a dynamic Swing GUI. I need to add/delete `JPanels` when I click on add/delete button. I am not able to add `JPanels` dynamically. Initially `JPanel` loads but the array of `JPanels` fail to work. How do I do it?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.JobHoldUntil;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AccessoryFileChooser2 extends JFrame {
  JFileChooser chooser = null;
  JLabel statusbar;
  JLabel file;
  JCheckBox checkBox;
  int count;
  int increment;
  JPanel [] panel = new JPanel[10]; //array

  public AccessoryFileChooser2() {
    setSize(350, 200);
    count=0;
    increment=1;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final Container c = getContentPane();

    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    checkBox =new JCheckBox("");
    String fileName = "Choose File Name";
   file = new JLabel(fileName);
    final JButton accButton = new JButton("Browse");
    final JButton add = new JButton("Add");
    final JButton validate = new JButton("Validate");
    final JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");

    accButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(AccessoryFileChooser2.this);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          statusbar.setText(
           (
            chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
        }
      }
    });

    statusbar = new JLabel("Output of your selection will go here");
    chooser = new JFileChooser();


   final JPanel panels =new JPanel();

   //JPanel panel2 =new JPanel();
   panel[count]=new JPanel();
   panel[count].add(checkBox);
   panel[count].add(file);
   panel[count].add(accButton );
   panel[count].add(statusbar);
   c.add(panel[count],BorderLayout.CENTER);
   panels.add(add);
   panels.add(delete);
   panels.add(validate);

   add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
          count=count+1;;
          increment=increment+1;;
          panel[count]=new JPanel();
           System.out.println("You clicked the ADD button");

           panel[count].add(checkBox);
           panel[count].add(file);
           panel[count].add(accButton );
           panel[count].add(statusbar);
           panel[count].revalidate();
           panel[count].repaint();
           panel[count].updateUI();
           c.add(panel[count]);

       }
   });

   delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           increment--;
           System.out.println("You clicked the Delete button");
           System.out.println(checkBox.isSelected());
           for (int i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
               JCheckBox box=(JCheckBox) panel[i].getComponent(0);
               if(box.isSelected()){
   c.remove(panel[i]);
   }
        }

       }
   });

   validate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           System.out.println("You clicked the Validate button");
       }
   });


   c.add(panels,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    AccessoryFileChooser2 afc = new AccessoryFileChooser2();
    afc.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not that not correct, there are lots of newbie mistakes,

1/ because same way as you created array for `JPanels`

```
JPanel [] panel = new JPanel[10];
```

you need to create `Array` for its `JComponents`, because one JComponent could be added only once time

EDIT: partial amended/changed code diplayed this issue

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AccessoryFileChooser2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFileChooser chooser = null;
    private JLabel statusbar;
    private JLabel file;
    private JCheckBox checkBox;
    private int count;
    private int increment = 10;
    private JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panels = new JPanel();
    private JPanel[] panel = new JPanel[increment]; //array
    private JButton accButton = new JButton("Browse");
    private JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    private JButton validate = new JButton("Validate");
    private JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");

    public AccessoryFileChooser2() {
        count = 0;
        parentPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1, 10, 10));
        checkBox = new JCheckBox("");
        String fileName = "Choose File Name";
        file = new JLabel(fileName);
        accButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(AccessoryFileChooser2.this);
                if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    statusbar.setText((chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                }
            }
        });
        statusbar = new JLabel("Output of your selection will go here");
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        panel[count] = new JPanel();
        panel[count].add(checkBox);
        panel[count].add(file);
        panel[count].add(accButton);
        panel[count].add(statusbar);
        panel[count].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 40));
        panel[count].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        parentPanel.add(panel[count]);
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (count < increment - 1) {
                    count += 1;
                    panel[count] = new JPanel();
                    System.out.println("You clicked the ADD button");
                    panel[count].add(checkBox);
                    panel[count].add(file);
                    panel[count].add(accButton);
                    panel[count].add(statusbar);
                    panel[count].revalidate();
                    panel[count].repaint();
                    //panel[count].updateUI();
                    parentPanel.add(panel[count]);
                    parentPanel.revalidate();
                    parentPanel.repaint();
                    pack();
                    if (count == increment - 1) {
                        addButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked the Delete button");
                System.out.println(checkBox.isSelected());
                /*for (int i = 0; i < parentPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                JCheckBox box = (JCheckBox) panel[i].getComponent(0);
                if (box.isSelected()) {
                parentPanel.remove(panel[i]);
                }
                }*/
            }
        });
        validate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked the Validate button");
            }
        });
        panels.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 10, 10));
        panels.add(addButton);
        panels.add(delete);
        panels.add(validate);
        add(parentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panels, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AccessoryFileChooser2 afc = new AccessoryFileChooser2();
    }
}
```

with this output to the GUI

[image]

2/ and so on ...

don't do it this way, there is possible a lots of issues with performance, if you add and remove `JPanel[]` lots of times ..., GUI would be freeze or will be un-responsive

it would be better to look for `JTable` with one `TableColumn` as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355544/how-to-implement-dynamic-gui-in-swing/6355910#6355910)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ya i am new to Swings. So trying some things to get familiar.

Answer (score 1):

When adding or removing components from a visible GUI the general code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The revalidate basically invoke the layout manager.

The repaint makes sure the components are repainted in case the layout has changed.

Comment: Hi, it works for me with revalidate(); only,  repaint() method is necessary? why ?

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi, repaint() is generally not necessary when you only add a component. However, sometimes if you remove and then add a component you may need to force the repaint because the layout manager may think the panel is the same size and not invoke repaint().

Answer (score 0):

Add `c.validate()` after `c.add(panel[count]);` to update the GUI.

It is also recommended to check the current number of `JPanel`s, because this way, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` pretty fast...

Comment: And does it help? according to docs you have to call it after `add`

Comment: I have added c.validate as c.revalidate is not present. But its still not working.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: try calling `invalidate()` before

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with:

```
repaint();
validate();
```

after making changes to the gui at run time.  When I create, remove, move panels I call these two methods on the component/container.