# Active Elements in swing JTree, JTable or JList

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jlist

I need a Container with similar `JPanel`s lined up one below the other which can be selected.  I could:

1. Use a `JList` with a custom renderer but those `JPanel`s would be passive elements, that's not what I want.
2. Implement my own Container with 'active' `JPanel`s but those would not be selectable. Or could they made selectable?
   *Maybe a `MouseListener` and access to the system default selected-background-colors could be a way but it seems a bit too much effort*
3. Use a `JTable` or `JTree` with custom cell editors rendering the 'active' `JPanel`. But these active parts would only react at the 'second' click, first to activate the editor, second to perform the real action of the `JPanel`. this is also not acceptable.

---

To get a more visual impression, here is an example of what this could mean:

A `JList` containing list items which have each two functional `JButtons`.

Comment: *"..a bit too much effort"*  Sometimes programmers have to put down the coffee & donuts & actually program.  :(

Comment: It is not like I want not to do this. But I prefer solutions where I can build on existing things instead of rewrite something already there.

Comment: regarding 3) when or whether editing is started is up to the implementation of CellRenderer: implement isCellEditable(EventObject) as needed

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, simply putting a `JPanel` inside a `JList` doesn't quite work as you'd like. The `JPanel` will be passive and won't receive events - essentially all that is happening is your `JPanel` is simply being drawn, it's not a living component.

Instead of using a `JList` to put your panels in a list, use a list-like layout manager, such as `BoxLayout` or `GridLayout`. If you want all your panels to be the same size, use `GridLayout` with only a single column.

- [How to Use GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
- [How to use BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Comment: This would be my second point. And totally missing the selectability of the Items.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your "example". If you want two functional buttons, then use a JTable where the functional buttons are contained is separate columns. Then your data would be displayed in other columns.

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

your question(s) isn't clear for me, maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355544/how-to-implement-dynamic-gui-in-swing/6355910#6355910)

there is [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), with one `TableColumn` but without `TableHeader`, contains [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) with active `JComponents` inside (you can implements [TableCellEditor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for all JComponents) as [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), [JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) and [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)