# java swing customize table cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In java Swing table, how to split a cell into two, one is TextField, another one is a checkbox. I have done some codes, but doesn't work. thanks

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JTextField fld = new JTextField();
            JCheckBox chx = new JCheckBox();
            cell.add(fld);  // Doesn't work
            cell.add(chx);  // Doesn't work

            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A renderer is used to render (display) some data. It's not used to enter data. Why would you want to have such a renderer? Also, the component returned by `super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` is a JLabel. You're not supposed to add elements to a JLabel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) in this case you have to define for `LayoutManager`, because `JLabel/JComponent` (by default return `TableCellRenderer`) doesn't [implemented any LayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel)

2) put `JPanel` [nested another JComponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355910/714968) (`JPanel` has by default `FlowLayout`) into Cell

3) most confortable will be put `JTextField` to one Column and `Boolean` value (returns `JCheckBox`) to another Column