# JTable Key Event Not Fired

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, keyevent

I am using a TableCellEditor For my column (ButtonColumns) as follows.
When i enter the down key the key event associated with the Jtable not fired . Please guide me regarding this obstacle, Los of Thanks in advance. The below SSCCE is as follows

```
class ButtonEditor_Utility extends DefaultCellEditor {

protected JButton button;



public ButtonEditor_Utility() {
button.setActionCommand(tableName);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fireEditingStopped();
        }
    });
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
        button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        button.setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }

    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    return button;
}



public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}

protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
}
```

}

```
 Class Test extent JFframe{

  public void    AddButtonColumn(){
 tblDetailInfo.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(
 new ButtonEditor_Utility(new JCheckBox(), this, 1, selectedRow,    this,null, "TestDB"));}
```

// Below Event is not responding on the Down Key
//whose key code is 40

```
    private void tblDetailInfoKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == 40) {

        int rowId = tblDetailInfo.getRowCount() - 1;

        setSelectedRow(rowId);
        tblDetailInfo.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        tblDetailInfo.changeSelection(rowId, 0, false, false);
        tblDetailInfo.requestFocus();
        tblDetailInfo.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(tblDetailInfo.getCellRect(rowId, 0, true)));
        AddDetailRow();

    }
}  

   private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){                      AddButtonColumn(); }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Test test = new Test();


            test.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
} }
```

}

Comment: Not *Compilable*. Not *Self-Contained*. As for *Short*, it's a stretch.

Comment: couldn't understand your comment

Comment: Then you are using an acronym without understanding. SSCCE = *Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Example*.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik what is in compatiibality in this code

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Actually I am adding some botton and combo columns and  my key event for jtable is not working as simple as that.

Comment: If it's so simple, why don't you provide an SSCCE.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Please provide solution if you know lots ofythanks and points i will give u.

Comment: I don't know the solution. If you had an SSCCE ready, however, I could give a quick look.

Comment: @mKorbel Please give me solution to the problem  I am adding some botton and combo columns to jtable and my key event for jtable is not working .

Comment: @Prog_Anila 1) what do you want to do with (botton) JButtons and JComboBox, 2) because part of things are in your code, another part in the comments and be sure anyone can lost here, 3) KeyEvent not firing because required Focus, only Editor can returns Focus, 4) as Marko mentioned post an SSCCE, 5) for why reason is there Editor, there are two JTables???

Comment: _give me solution_ sure: give me money first ;-) Seriously: that's not how this site is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a `JLabel` and a `KeyEvent` into service as a table cell editor, use an actual `TableCellEditor` such as @camickr's [`ButtonColumn`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). This [`TableTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559747/230513) illustrates one way to use [`ButtonColumn`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) in a `JTable`. The advantage is that you get all the familiar [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for navigation (arrow keys) and activation (space key).