# How to implement button in a vector

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jbutton

In my table. I want to put some buttons into each row that I can press.
But I do not know how to do it

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {
    java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }

        data.add(vector);
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah it is how to put buttons in my JTable

Comment: Have a look here: [How to make a JButton in a JTable cell click-able?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555938/how-to-make-a-jbutton-in-a-jtable-cell-click-able) for several good suggestions. You can search this site for other similar questions and answers.

Comment: Ok. So you want buttons in each table cell... And how is your code related with it?

Comment: Also please have a look at Rob Camick's blog article titled [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). His blog is a treasure chest full of Swing explanations and examples and other Java gems.

Answer (score 1):

For doing this you have to first look at,

1. [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
2. How to render a cell in `JTable` as [Button example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

Not only the above stated example, you have many sources which shows how to add a button in a JTable cell.