# How to add mouseListener to two different views in one column of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jsp, jtable, jsplitpane

I am having a problem regarding adding the mouseListener to the separate views in one column of jTable.
[image]

I have tried to design this using SplitPane. But then i have a problem in handle the click event in differentiating the views. I am not able to identify whether mouse click is done on **Edit or Delete**

Please help.

Comment: You'll need a custom [`CellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513), not a `MouseListener`.

Comment: for other columns i need mouseListener to do other tasks

Comment: This possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24367799/230513) explains how to distinguish button clicks inside a table cell.